# Why the value of input elements are not changing?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm learning Javascript and right now I'm trying to build a simple calculator.

I have added four buttons for basic arithmetic operation and three input elements.

I have attached eventListener to every button. The problem I am facing is when I input two numbers and click on any one of the four buttons I can see the result for only half second and then every input value clear away.

Here is the code.

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('ADD').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 + num2;
});
document.getElementById('SUB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 - num2;
});
document.getElementById('MUL').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 * num2;
});
document.getElementById('DIV').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 / num2;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="first">Number 1:</label>
    <input id="first" type="text" value="">
    <br><br>

    <label for="second">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="second">
    <br><br>

    <label for="result">Result :</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="result">
    <br><br>

    <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
    <button id="MUL">MUL</button>
    <button id="DIV">DIV</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need the form tag in this case. So as an alternative to what the answers below show you, you could also simply remove the form tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it's a form. Add an event listener to make sure the form doesn't refresh the page (default action when `action` is not given or invalid):

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: Could you please explain the `e => e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Take the parameter `e` (the event object as an argument) - `=>` (arrow function) - `e.preventDefault()` (prevent the default action of the event object, in this case form submission).

Answer (score 3):

Simply add  `type="button"` in your button's

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');

document.getElementById('ADD').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 + num2;
});

document.getElementById('SUB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 - num2;
});

document.getElementById('MUL').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 * num2;
});

document.getElementById('DIV').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 / num2;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="first">Number 1:</label>
    <input id="first" type="text" value="">
    <br><br>

    <label for="second">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="second">
    <br><br>

    <label for="result">Result :</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="result">
    <br><br>

    <button type="button" id="ADD">ADD</button>
    <button type="button" id="SUB">SUB</button>
    <button type="button" id="MUL">MUL</button>
    <button type="button" id="DIV">DIV</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your mark up are inside `form` element, clicking the button will submit form. either remove `form` or add `event.preventDefault();` inside the click event;

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('ADD').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 + num2;
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById('SUB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 - num2;
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById('MUL').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 * num2;
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById('DIV').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 / num2;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="first">Number 1:</label>
    <input id="first" type="text" value="">
    <br><br>

    <label for="second">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="second">
    <br><br>

    <label for="result">Result :</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="result">
    <br><br>

    <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
    <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
    <button id="MUL">MUL</button>
    <button id="DIV">DIV</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your form an action `action="javascript:void(0);"`

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('ADD').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 + num2;
});
document.getElementById('SUB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 - num2;
});
document.getElementById('MUL').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 * num2;
});
document.getElementById('DIV').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 / num2;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
  <label for="first">Number 1:</label>
  <input id="first" type="text" value="">
  <br><br>

  <label for="second">Number 2:</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="second">
  <br><br>

  <label for="result">Result :</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="result">
  <br><br>

  <button id="ADD">ADD</button>
  <button id="SUB">SUB</button>
  <button id="MUL">MUL</button>
  <button id="DIV">DIV</button>

</form>
```

I don't think in this case you even need a form tag, you can simply do it without one :

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('ADD').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 + num2;
});
document.getElementById('SUB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 - num2;
});
document.getElementById('MUL').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 * num2;
});
document.getElementById('DIV').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
  res.value = num1 / num2;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for="first">Number 1:</label>
<input id="first" type="text" value="">
<br><br>

<label for="second">Number 2:</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="second">
<br><br>

<label for="result">Result :</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="result">
<br><br>

<button id="ADD">ADD</button>
<button id="SUB">SUB</button>
<button id="MUL">MUL</button>
<button id="DIV">DIV</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove "form" html tag. Form is getting submitted after you click any button, so result is wiping out.